# Resizing primary parition with extended one in command line

Tags: partition, parted, resize2fs

I want to extend my primary partition with a new extended one that I created with `parted`.

Here is my actual setup (parted print free):

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  42,6GB  42,6GB  primary   ext4         boot
        42,6GB  42,6GB  497kB             Free Space
 2      42,6GB  59,1GB  16,5GB  extended               lba
        42,6GB  59,1GB  16,5GB            Free Space
```

When I try to run `resize2fs /dev/sda1`, it won't take the 'free' space of 16,5GB.

How should I do it?

Comment: Remove the extended partition and then try to resize because this space is not free, its in use by extended partition.

Comment: 42,6GB  59,1GB  16,5GB           Free Space
So now it's free.
$ resize2fs /dev/sda1 says that it has nothing to do

Comment: Before resize2fs you need to extend the partition. With fdisk change then end block of `/dev/sda1`

Comment: I see that I need to delete the partition. Does that mean it will erase all data within that partition?

Comment: If you do not have any logical partition in this extended partition you have no data in this partition. If you have any data (somehow) you should shrink this partition

Comment: Now I only have the primary partition. The extended one has been removed. For resize2fr, I saw on tutorials that I first need to delete the primary partition and resize it. Does the 'delete the primary partition' will delete the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62500/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-kaymaz).